# How to get a value of a list,when click on submit

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, struts2

```html
<s:select label="Select a Database" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select database" list="#{'MySQL':'MySQL', 'Microsoft SQL Server':'Microsoft SQL Server', 'Oracle':'Oracle', 'PostgreSQL':'PostgreSQL'}" name="dbname" onchange="getSchemas(this.value)"/>
    <s:submit value="Submit" onclick="submitDB()" />
```

Here I want to remove `onchange="getSchemas(this.value)` and I want to call same function on submit button, but how can I get `this.value`  `onclick="submitDB()` ?

Comment: Read this - http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/unobtrusive-javascript-important.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `select` element to the function

```
onclick="submitDB(this.form['dbname'])"
```

Then use it in the function to get the value

```
function submitDB(el) {

 val = el.options[el.selectedIndex].value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Struts JSP code:**

```
<s:select label="Select a Database" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select database" 
          list="#{'MySQL':'MySQL', 'Microsoft SQL Server':'Microsoft SQL Server', 
                  'Oracle':'Oracle', 'PostgreSQL':'PostgreSQL'}" 
          name="dbname" id="databaseType" />                        
<s:submit value="Submit" onclick="submitDB()" />
```

**javascript code :**

```
function submitDB() {           
    var dbname = document.getElementById("databaseType").value;     
}
```

Comment: struts jsp code:
<s:select label="Select a Database" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select database" list="#{'MySQL':'MySQL', 'Microsoft SQL Server':'Microsoft SQL Server', 'Oracle':'Oracle', 'PostgreSQL':'PostgreSQL'}" name="dbname" id="databaseType" />      <s:submit value="Submit" onclick="submitDB()" />
    java script code :
    function submitDB() {   
 var dbname = document.getElementById("databaseType").value;  
 }